# Error while loading package in Intellij after adding Maven dependencies (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using intelij ultimate trial. I'm new to programming and a friend recommended I learn functional programming before object oriented programming. Searching the web I decided to learn Scala. The problem is I can't even set up IDE environment. I copied the dependencies but I'm unsure what they do. I'm just following along a coursera course right now. I don't know what the issue is. I don't know if I provided enough information. I used an online IDE when I was learning python

**Currently using**:
SDK 2.13.4
JDK 1.8

**I've tried**:
changing JDK to 11.0, 11.03, 13.0, and 15.0. I also changed SDK 2.11, 2.12.9,2.13.5 witch each JDK

**Maven dependencies I'm using**:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalaj-http_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
            <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalafx_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1-R21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-json_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Specific error I'm receiving**:

Error:scalac: error while loading package, class file '/Users/panda/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.4/scala-library-2.13.4.jar(scala/collection/immutable/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/error reading Scala signature of package.class: Scala signature package has wrong version
expected: 5.0
found: 5.2 in package.class)

Comment: By the way, there is also an online playground for Scala called Scastie  https://scastie.scala-lang.org/

Comment: Maybe you start a little smaller - does Scala work without the IDE? 
Just call scala -version.

Comment: The assignments and videos are all using IntelliJ. I think it will be easier to just learn how to use IntelliJ. I also think once I'm able to understand and fix this error it should get easier? idk its really frustrating. I'm just skipping the practice problems and watching the videos in the mean time

Comment: Wow that is a lot of dependencies just to learn scala.  I think you are biting off more than you can chew here.  Out of the box IntelliJ ultimate supports Scala, your best bet is probably to look at the JetBrains site for its Scala blog, and and checkout if it has any begins tutorials.  Back in the day Khan Academy had a very good course on Scala and functional programming delivered by the creator of Scala.

Comment: You should also make sure you are using the right JDK for the version of Scala you are targeting.

Comment: I copied and pasted all of them. So the JDK is the problem? I tried changing it to the 3 options 1.8, 11.03, and 13.00 but all 3 failed. I'm going to try all the combinations see if it fixes it. What does this mean? I found it on a different site. https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11847.   This is due to using a pre-2.13 compiler with the 2.13 library on the class path.

...
This can happen by supplying -toolcp or a stale CLASSPATH in the environment.